# Interacting with HTML variables from BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have written code which takes the Hotel Name and the price from bookings.com from a specific URL. I am trying to get the tool to only output the name and price of the one hotel I am looking for. I can output all the names and prices of the hotels on the page, but when I run an IF statement to try and output a singular one it doesn't work. I've tried putting Str() around the code which selects the hotel name and price but that causes nothing to output. The current code just returns 'Wrong Hotel'. Am I unable to manipulate the variables once scraped? As I also want to compare prices of hotels.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36'}

url = 'https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?aid=355028&sid=d2a902f346650dc0b748848763652bdc&sb=1&src=searchresults&src_elem=sb&error_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Fsearchresults.en-gb.html%3Faid%3D355028%3Bsid%3Dd2a902f346650dc0b748848763652bdc%3Btmpl%3Dsearchresults%3Bcheckin_month%3D5%3Bcheckin_monthday%3D8%3Bcheckin_year%3D2021%3Bcheckout_month%3D5%3Bcheckout_monthday%3D13%3Bcheckout_year%3D2021%3Bcity%3D-2601889%3Bclass_interval%3D1%3Bdest_id%3D-2601889%3Bdest_type%3Dcity%3Bdtdisc%3D0%3Bfrom_sf%3D1%3Bgroup_adults%3D1%3Bgroup_children%3D0%3Binac%3D0%3Bindex_postcard%3D0%3Blabel_click%3Dundef%3Bno_rooms%3D1%3Boffset%3D0%3Bpostcard%3D0%3Broom1%3DA%3Bsb_price_type%3Dtotal%3Bshw_aparth%3D1%3Bslp_r_match%3D0%3Bsrc%3Dsearchresults%3Bsrc_elem%3Dsb%3Bsrpvid%3D6eda76c5afe000a5%3Bss%3DLondon%3Bss_all%3D0%3Bssb%3Dempty%3Bsshis%3D0%3Bssne%3DLondon%3Bssne_untouched%3DLondon%3Btop_ufis%3D1%3Bsig%3Dv1yWyN9mHA%3B&ss=London+Marriott+Hotel+County+Hall%2C+London%2C+Greater+London%2C+United+Kingdom&is_ski_area=&ssne=London&ssne_untouched=London&city=-2601889&checkin_year=2021&checkin_month=5&checkin_monthday=8&checkout_year=2021&checkout_month=5&checkout_monthday=13&group_adults=1&group_children=0&no_rooms=1&from_sf=1&ss_raw=Marriott+London&ac_position=1&ac_langcode=en&ac_click_type=b&dest_id=36867&dest_type=hotel&place_id_lat=51.5010959924622&place_id_lon=-0.119165182113647&search_pageview_id=6eda76c5afe000a5&search_selected=true&search_pageview_id=6eda76c5afe000a5&ac_suggestion_list_length=5&ac_suggestion_theme_list_length=0'


response=requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")


for item in soup.select('.sr_property_block'):
    try:
        hotelname = item.select('.sr-hotel__name')[0].get_text()
        hotelprice = item.select('.bui-price-display__value')[0].get_text()

        if hotelname == 'London Marriott Hotel County Hall':
            print(hotelname)
            print(hotelprice)
        else:
            print('Wrong Hotel')        
       
        #print('---------------')
        
    except Exception as e:
        print('')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two spaces in `hotelname` after scraping, a leading space char and a trailing space char. Use `strip()` to eliminate leading and trailing space characters in `hotelname`.

`hotelname = hotelname.strip()`